# How to move an image left of text in a table column in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I've tried to mess around with inline styling to move the images just the left of the text in a particular column but for some of the rows the images overlap or the text is too far to the right as can be seen in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QddSC.png

```
 <TableCell align="right" > <Avatar src={n.image} style={{width: 25, height: 25, position: 'absolute'  }}/> <span style={{color: '#0066ff', cursor: 'pointer' }} >{n.name}</span> </TableCell>
```

Does anyone know how to move the image just left of the text and fix these gaps and overlapping problems thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code::

```
<TableCell align="right" > 
    <Avatar src={n.image} style={{width: 25, height: 25, display: 'inline-block', vertical-align: 'top'  }}/> 
    <span style={{color: '#0066ff', cursor: 'pointer',  display: 'inline-block', vertical-align: 'top', width: 'calc(100% - 35px)' }} >{n.name}</span> 
</TableCell>
```

Comment: I had to mess around with the width and height values, but the code works. Thanks very much.